# Reading and writing structures to a binary file

Tags: vba, file, data-structures, binary, read-write

Using the `FilePut()` method I saved a few arrays of a user-defined structure to a binary file in sequence, This seemed to work since the files have data in them but how can I read them back from the file into the array again as they originally were?

Using `FileGet()` I get this error back

> Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.

```
FileOpen(1, gamename, OpenMode.Binary)
FilePut(1, CurrentPlayers)
FileClose(1)
```

and to read back

```
FileOpen(1, gameSave, OpenMode.Binary)
FileGet(1, CurrentPlayers)  'Error occurs here
FileClose(1)
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @Comintern Added my code, the read and the write happen in separate routines

Answer (score 0):

You question is not complete. But one of my guesses is that you might not be resetting the file pointer to the beginning before reading what you wrote.

Comment: I close the file after writing and reopen it later to read, shouldn't that start it at the beginning for the file?